# Ubuntu 22.04 Wayland remap Caps-Lock to F13

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, wayland

As the title suggests I want to remap the Caps-Lock key to F13 on my linux machine. But currently everything corresponding to Keyboard remapping in Ubuntu is a mess.

I want a more convenient way for the arrow keys. My idea:

- Caps-Lock = Esc
- Caps-Lock + j = Left
- Caps-Lock + k = Down
- Caps-Lock + l = Right
- Caps-Lock + i = Up

I've done a lot of research and found no solution. It would be nice to have something like AHK on Linux. It works great for Windows.

To achieve this goal mentioned above, I need to remap the Caps-Lock Key to another Keycode, because Caps-Lock is handled by the system. So I thought there might be a way to use F13 as a modifier key.

If you have any suggestions how to achieve a similar result, please tell me. I really love Ubuntu, but it's always such a pain to get things working with Wayland.